# How to pre-fill radio buttons using query parameters?

Tags: html, forms, autofill

I want to pre-fill radio inputs while redirecting to some website. I don't have inner access to that website so the only way I found is to use query parameters. There are different types of inputs in that website. The problem I faced is with pre-filling radio buttons.

The radio buttons inside form looks like this,

```
<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate1" value="1" style="font-size: bold">
<label for="cate1" style="font-size: bold">Category 1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate2" value="2" style="font-size: bold">
<label for="cate2" style="font-size: bold">Category 2</label>
br
<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate3" value="3" style="font-size: bold">
<label for="cate3" style="font-size: bold">Category 3</label>
```

I tried to autofill these radio buttons using query params as,

```
domain.com?cate=1
```

But this doesn't work. I mean radio buttons do not get checked.

Is there any way to pre-fill these buttons using query params?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Allowing arbitrary third-party sites to use a link to cause a visitor's browser to prefill a form on a different site would be a serious security risk.

You need the site to use a programming language (typically server-side, but you could also do it with client-side JavaScript) which will parse the query string, and then set the `checked` attribute of the associated input (or the `checked` property via DOM in the case of client-side JS).

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's possible but not feasible.

Your best bet would be to try to submit the form without filling in some required fields and hope that the form uses GET for submission. If so, and if the form validates on the server side, you might be redirected to a page where the URL will show the correct parameters to be passed. Once you know these URL parameters, and if the code on the server side pre-populates the form with these URL parameters, you'll get what you want.

Comment: Exaclty, I am done with other fields and I have filled only required fields. I also know correct parameters to be filled. The only problem is with radio button.  I didn't get radio button while passing its name with value in URL parameter as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use php here. Get the value from query parameter and add checked attribute according to query parameter value.

```html
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['cate'])) $cate=$_GET['cate'];

    else $cate=0; //or any null value

?>

<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate1" value="1" style="font-size: bold" <?php echo ($cate == 1) ? "checked" : ""; ?>  >

<label for="cate1" style="font-size: bold">Category 1</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate2" value="2" style="font-size: bold" <?php echo ($cate == 2) ? "checked" : ""; ?> >

<label for="cate2" style="font-size: bold">Category 2</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="cate" id="cate3" value="3" style="font-size: bold"  <?php echo ($cate == 3) ? "checked" : ""; ?> >

<label for="cate3" style="font-size: bold">Category 3</label>
```

Comment: No, they can't. They explicitly said "I don't have inner access to that website"